# Emulating paste in Selenium IDE 2.5.0

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm using sendKeys to try and emulate a paste (Ctrl+V) for something stored in the clipboard, as it stands I have correctly targeted the element where I wanted my content to be pasted, but retrieve no results.

This is my test case so far:

```
<tr>
<td>sendKeys</td>
<td>css=input[type="text"]</td>
<td>${KEY_CONTROL}</td>
</tr>
```

Do I need to use keyChord for multiple inputs or could I just use:

```
<tr>
<td>sendKeys</td>
<td>css=#customerLogo &gt; img</td>
<td>${KEY_CONTROL} + "v"</td>
</tr>
```

My problem is the combination of inputs (especially normal "ASCII" characters) which I don't know how to input.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is the use case for this?  I don't see any use for this.  Why not just use `storeEval` then reference it using `${SOMETHING}`

Comment: Basically, i want to use a set of text that has been copied to be pasted into a textfield which uses ajax to filter a table's results. Im thinking using storeEval will be enough, the only thing i dont like is that i will have to hard code the expected stored value.

Comment: @sircapsalot It happens when you need to simulate Exactly that event